# How to Submit a CSR for a Let's Encrypt Certificate Using Posh-ACME in PowerShell?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, csr

I'm working on issuing a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for my domain using Posh-ACME in PowerShell, specifically for a wildcard domain (*.mydomain.com). I have already generated a CSR, since it's shared host and going the CSR way is the only option that I have, and now need guidance on how to submit this CSR using Posh-ACME.

**Steps Completed:**

1. Installed Posh-ACME using Install-Module -Name Posh-ACME.
2. Imported the Posh-ACME module with Import-Module Posh-ACME.
3. Set Let's Encrypt as the ACME server and created a new ACME account.
4. Generated a CSR for *.mydomain.com.

**Where I'm Stuck:**
I am not sure how to proceed with submitting the CSR I've generated to Let's Encrypt using Posh-ACME. Most documentation and tutorials I've found do not focus on CSR submission but rather on generating a new certificate directly.

**My Question Is:**
Can anyone provide guidance or a method for submitting an existing CSR to Let's Encrypt using Posh-ACME in PowerShell? Are there specific cmdlets or steps in Posh-ACME for handling CSR submissions for SSL certificate issuance?

I am open to using any alternative that would get this done.

Comment: Using DNS challenge is documented here: https://poshac.me/docs/v4/Guides/Using-DNS-Challenge-Aliases/

Answer (score 0):

[New-PACertificate -CSRPath](https://poshac.me/docs/v4/Functions/New-PACertificate/#fromcsr)

---

The first getting started example in documentation is likely to be an easy use case with minimal deviation from defaults. Full use of the feature set tends to require reading longer guides or reference material.